# How can I forward a querystring passed to nodejs to a page served via res.render?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Within my nodejs file I am rendering a page called foo.html. Inside of foo.html, I am using ajax to pull variables from a querystring and load an appropriate xml doc accordingly.
The problem is, if I run my nodejs server, we'll call it localhost, and I append the querystring to that, then the server will consume the querystring rather than the ajax call inside of foo.html.

Is there a way to forward the querystring directly to foo.html?

From inside the nodejs file, server.js:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    if (query) {
        if (query.screen == "page1") {
            res.render('foo.html');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can think of 2 ways of doing this

```
1st way -) you can change your rendering engine and pass the query string variables as local variables to the template and store those values as variables inside a <script></script> tag

2nd way -) keep the html but don't render the file  load it and modify it to contain the same script tag with the variables,
```

in both cases once your page is loaded your JS will be able to access the variables

-------------HTML FILE----------------

```
<script>
   var a=/*text-to-replace-for-A*/;
   var b=/*text-to-replace-for-B*/;
</script>
```

--------------REQUEST HANDLER-----------

```
 var fs=require('fs'); //this goes in the require section

 //this goes inside your function
 fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var finalHTML=data.replace(/\/\*text-to-replace-for-A\*\//g,variableA).replace(/\/\*text-to-replace-for-B\*\//g,variableB);
   res.send(finalHTML)
 });
```

something like that should notice i am using a simple readfile and send which is not the fastest solution but is the simplest one using html modification. you can also use streams to modify the files in memory on the fly. you can find the readfile function reference at: http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback

Comment: I'm fairly new to nodejs.  If I'm not rendering the file statically..We'll call it index.html, and there are some css and js dependencies it has... How would I load it and modify it?  Code example or link?  I am accepting your answer, regardless.